# efibootmgr on Arch Linux incorrectly reports empty root

Tags: arch-linux, boot, uefi

I create an EFI stub using (newlines just for easier viewing):

```
efibootmgr
 --disk /dev/nvme0n1
 --part 1
 --create
 --label "Arch Linux"
 --loader /vmlinuz-linux
 --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=my-partuuid-here rw initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux.img'
 --verbose
```

`efibootmgr -v` also confirms that the parameters are there.

However on boot I get dropped into the emergency console with the message `ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.`

I can successfully boot using:

```
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 new_root
exit
```

But I don't want to enter this on every boot. Why does UEFI think root is set to the empty string when it is in fact set to a nonempty value?

The PC is a Dell OptiPlex 5070.

P.S.: Could it be the problem described in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178154 where the parameters are not given to the image? That post describes another model but of the same company.

Comment: Oh sorry it was like that already, I wrote it down incorrectly, I fixed it now, thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Yes, it seems your Dell ignores the kernel arguments. Found another [post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1864424#p1864424) with a workaround. Maybe give it a try?

Comment: @Freddy: I use systemd-boot for now, which seems simpler than the workaround, but thanks for the link!